# Why does this optoisolator circuit behave like that?

Tags: opto-isolator

I use 4n25 optoisolator IC. When the duty cycle of Arduino is close to 100%, I expect the voltage across R2 to be 18 V. This happens when R2 is 47 kΩ.

I work in a group and my team found that they read the number 47k by mistake. R2 should be 4.7 kΩ. When they replaced the resistor, the voltage across it became 16 V. It never reaches 18 V although the duty cycle is 100%.

What is the reason behind this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXC1z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your output transistor is not fully turning on with that load.

Comment: Are you sure it is a 4N25? I could explain this if it were a 4N27

Comment: yes I'm sure. Do you meant that CTR in 4n27 is high not enough?

Comment: @Trevor I now that the only way to fully turn a transsistor on is to pass enough current in the base. It does not depend on the load. Would you explain what you think, Please?

Comment: @MichaelGeorge: correct. Your part may simply be degraded from a lot of use.

Comment: Think of it like a normal transistor, because your R is at the emitter, the base current is affected by that resistance. The larger R the less Ibase... so it will not turn on as hard.

Comment: @Trevor Oh that's right. I forget it.

Comment: That looks like an emitter follower (common collector) circuit rather than a switch (common emitter).

Comment: @Trevor, (also JIm Dearden) The fact that R2 is in the emitter circuit rather than the collector circuit has no effect on the current flow through the transistor-- it would be the same either way. There is no electrical connection to the base, so there's no VBE involved per se. The transistor just acts as a 2-terminal current source (well, "current conveyor") whose current is set by the light from the LED, and hence by ILED.  In fact, the larger R2, the _closer_ R2 will be to saturation, because the same IC (=IE) will cause larger voltage across R2, thus lower VCE.

Comment: @MichaelGeorge Fully turning on the transistor absolutely _does_ depend on the load. The smaller the load resistance, the higher the IC or IE (here) required to get a voltage drop across the load that leaves only ~0.2V across the transistor (transistor saturated = "fully on"). With R2 = 4.7k you need ~3.78mA IC, with 47k, only 0.378mA. In turn, the former will require ten times the base current, or light in the case of phototransistor, compared to the latter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do the math.

The output is driving 16 V across 4.7 kΩ, so is passing 3.4 mA.

On the input there is 5 V across 150 Ω and the LED.  According to the 4N25 datasheet, the forward drop of the LED can be 1.5 V.  The current is therefore ((5 V) - (1.5 V)) / (150 Ω) = 23 mA.

You are getting a current transfer ratio of (3.4 mA)/(23 mA) = 15%.   Now again look in the datasheet and see that the minimum guaranteed CTR is 20%.  Something is therefore not as expected.

The most likely culprit is that the digital output is not really 5 V when you try to draw 23 mA from it.  That's *a lot* to expect a digital output to do.  Check its datasheet.

Let's say for example (your job to look up the actual value), that the digital output can source 10 mA and drop to no less than 4.5 V in the process.  After the 1.5 V drop across the LED, the resistor must be at least (3.0 V)/(10 mA) = 300 Ω.

Now let's look at what the output should be for this example.  With 10 mA in and 20% CTR, you can expect 2 mA output current.  To drive a resistor all the way to 18 V, the resistor must be at least (18 V)/(2 mA) = 9 kΩ.

So change R1 to 300 Ω and R2 to 10 kΩ, and everything should work for this made-up example.  Look in the datasheet to see what the actual digital output source current and voltage at that current are, and plug in the numbers for your case.

Comment: ((5 V) - (1.5 V)) / (150 Ω) = 23.3 mA not 10 mA. It's just a math mistake but I understand the answer. Here's +1 for teaching me how to calculate the right value of emitter resistance. Thank you very much,

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I realized that mistake too, and was editing the answer as you wrote the comment.  Please check again.  I think it's fixed now, and the conclusion updated.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the numbers:

\$ I_{out}\ =\ \frac {16V} {4.7k} = 3.4mA\$

\$ I_{in}\ =\ \frac {5V - V_f} {150} = 23.3mA\$ for \$V_f\$ = 1.5V (Vf is the LED forward voltage)

\$CTR = \frac {I_{out}} {I_{in}} = \frac {3.4mA} {23.3mA} = 14.5\$%

So either the duty cycle is not quite 100% or the 4N25 is not operating correctly as it is stated to have a minimum CTR of 20%.

I would normally not be surprised if the emitter voltage was 0.5V lower than the collector.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like a normal transistor, because your R is at the emitter, the base current is affected by that resistance. The larger R the less Ibase... so it will not turn on as hard.